# Accessing feature importance in XGBoost version 0.6 (Python)

Tags: python, xgboost

I'm trying to to get the feature importance for my xgboost model but I'm always getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'`

I read that this might be a versioning issue, but I installed this in late December 2016 and I believe this is the version that supposedly fixed this problem.

Can anyone help me get the feature importances?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xgboost as xgb
print "XGB Version: " + str(xgb.__version__)

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))

x = df.ix[:,0:4]
y = df.ix[:,4]

mod = xgb.XGBModel()
mod.fit (x,y)

mod.feature_importances_
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Nothing wrong, it work perfect

Comment: Completely different for me. I'm getting `XGB Version: 0.6

AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b92670c50b42> in <module>()
     13 mod.fit (x,y)
     14 
---> 15 mod.feature_

AttributeError: 'XGBModel' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'`

Comment: How you install xgboost package ?